# How to insert text to QTextEdit according to combo box CurrentText?

Tags: qt5

In an application I am creating I have a combo box with a list of items and a QTextEdit (read only) below it.

I want to display certain text (it can be a plain text) according to which option is selected. I mean to create a combo box where the user can choose an option and a detailed description (in QTextEdit) of selected option.

How this can be achieved?

For now the only thing I had figured was using the Signal and Slot in Designer and connecting combo box with QTextView and setting currentTextChanged() - setText(). And it works nicely but it just sets the text from Combo Box into the QTextView... and that is not the thing I want.

I am using QtCreator 2.8.1 with Qt5.1.1 on Elementary OS Luna (Ubuntu derivative, Linux).

Comment: I store combo box strings in QStringList. I also have the "detailed descriptions" stored in an another QStringList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your own custom "setText" slot which will the QTextEdit's setText slot with the desired string content.

Basically, you need to have a mapping between the QComboBox options and the relevant texts displayed in the QTextEdit.

Comment: Actually I think that's the answer I am looking for. Thanks for pointing the right direction! :)

Answer (score 1):

it coule be easier to connect the `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int)` signal to a custom `SLOT` in your class.

then use that index on the `detailed description` list to access the text.

soo long zai